# XLSX to XML with schema map

Tags: python, xml, excel, xlsx, openpyxl

I have built a couple basic workflows using XML tools on top of XLSX workbooks that are mapped to an XML schema. You would enter data into the spreadsheet, export the XML and I had some scripts that would then work with the data.

Now I'm trying to eliminate that step and build a more integrated and portable tool that others could use easily by moving from XSLT/XQuery to Python. I would still like to use Excel for the data entry, but have the Python script read the XLSX file directly.

I found a bunch of easy to use libraries to read from Excel but they need to explicitly state what cells the data is in, like range('A1:C2') etc. The useful thing about using the XML maps was that users could resize  or even move tables to fit different rows and rename sheets. Is their a library that would let me select tables as units?

Another approach I tried was to just uncompress the XLSX and just parse the XML directly. The problem with that is that our data is quite complex (taking up to 30-50 sheets) and parsing that in the uncompressed XLSX structure is really daunting. I did find my XML schema within the uncompressed XLSX, so is there any way to reformat the data into this schema outside of Excel? (basically what Excel does when I save a workbook as an .xml file)

Comment: If your workflow can involve exporting to .csv that would make life much easier. Microsoft has a pretty vested interest in keeping others out of their formats. That being said, there *is* the win32 api that exists ([pywin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/)) that you may find helpful. Or search for 'python xlsx to csv'. Or if you *really* want to make things nice, just make a simple UI in Tkinter (or flask+html) for entering the data.

Comment: @WayneWerner: With all due respect, your comment makes you sound like you've never tried the available libraries for reading Excel files directly (chiefly xlrd and OpenPyXL). It is extremely easy to read Excel with these, in some ways easier than converting to CSV first. CSV is also famous for not being able to store type information (so you can't even distinguish between numbers and strings that look like numbers). OP's issue with the Excel libraries isn't something that would be fixed by converting to CSV first. If anything, converting to CSV first would make life *more* difficult.

Comment: @JohnY True story - I haven't tried any Excel libraries recently. If there are new libraries that make this easier then that's *awesome* for Python :)

Comment: @WayneWerner your point about the file format is valid – the specification seems a combination of incompetence and obfuscation – but the file format still has a lot of advantages over CSV, notably some degree of typing and people already have GUIs that can cope with most of the stuff: OpenOffice, LibreOffice, Google Docs all do a reasonable job. And this is not just about data entry so the Tkinter / Flask suggestion is off the mark.

Comment: @CharlieClark if my comment were an *answer* then yes, it would be entirely off the mark - which is why I left it as a comment. But the OP stated "I'm trying to eliminate that step and build a more integrated and portable tool that others could use easily" and "You would enter data into the spreadsheet, export the XML and I had some scripts that would then work with the data." I don't know how complicated the data entry is, but it *may* be reasonable to make a UI and skip the entire XML process entirely. It may not answer the question the OP asked, but it might solve their problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Excel format is pretty complicated with dependencies between components – you can't for example be sure of that the order of the worksheets in the folder worksheets has any bearing to what the file looks like in Excel.

I don't really understand exactly what you're trying to do but the existing libraries present an interface for client code that hides the XML layer. If you don't want that you'll have to root around for the parts that you find useful. In openpyxl you want to look at the stuff in `openpyxl/reader` specifically `worksheet.py`.

However, you might have better luck using lxml as this (using libxml2 in the background) will allow you load a single XML into Python and manipulate it directly using the `.objectify()` method. We don't do this in openpyxl because XML trees consume a lot of memory (and many people have very large worksheets) but the library for working with Powerpoint shows just how easy this can be.